# Calling flowRedirect after returning from subflow throws exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

```
<subflow-state id="callingSubflow" subflow="cz/fe/ui">
    <transition on="finish" to="goToResult"/>
</subflow-state>

<end-state id="goToResult" view="flowRedirect:cz/fe/ui/detail/flow"/>
```

With this configuration, after completing some webflow logic in subflow, flowRedirect does not happen, only the original page gets refreshed and I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active FlowSession to access; this FlowExecution has ended" exception.

When I don't go to "goToResult" state from subflow, flowRedirect works as expected.

When I don't use flowRedirect in the end state, the expected page is displayed correctly.

But when I use combination of these both, only refresh & exception happens.

Using Spring Web Flow 2.0.9

Answer (score 0):

when you are inside a subflow and in an end-state flow, the view argument is ignored.
try using view-state instead and see if that solves your issue

Comment: But I'm not calling flowRedirect from inside the subflow. Subflow ends at end-state with id "finish" and then in the main flow I go to "goToResult" end-state with flowRedirect.

Comment: that is weird... have you tried using a view-state instead just to see if it works?

Comment: I had - it started throwing IndexOutOfBounds while calling some method on some String with index -1 :) I've already rewritten the flow so that I don't call flowRedirect after returning from subflow. It's not so elegant now, but it works.